# Is it feasible to split data from differently formatted csv files in MS-SQL into several tables with one row per field of a file?

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv

I only found answers about how to import csv files into the database, for example as blob or as 1:1 representation of the table you are importing it into.

What I need is a little different: My team and I are tracking everything we do in a database. A lot of these tasks produce logfiles, benchmark results, etc., which are stored in CSV format. The number of columns are far from consistent and also the data could be completely different from file to file, e.g. it could be a log from fraps with frametimes in it or a log of CPU temparatures over an amount of time, or even something completely different.

Long story short, I came up with an idea, but - being far from a sql pro - I am not sure if it makes sense or if there is a more elegant solution.

Does this make sense to you:

[image]

We also need to deal with a lot of data that is produced, so please give me also your opinion if that is feasible with like 200 files per day which can easyly have a couple of thousands rows.

The purpose of all this will be, that we can generate reports form the stored data and perform analysis of the data. E.g. view it on a webpage in a graph or do calculations with it.

I'm limited to MS-SQL in this case, because that's what the current (quite complex) database is and I'm just adding a new schema with that functionality to it.

Currently we just archive the files on a raid and store a link to it in the database. So everyone who wants to do magic with the data needs to download every file he needs and then use R or Excel to create a visualization of the data.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you edit your question so you describe your proposed solution in the question itself?  The image you provided was very helpful in understanding your solution. Also, it would be helpful to mention which version of SQL server you're using (and whose... I'm assuming Microsoft SQL Server... but maybe it's Sybase...;)). Any case let us know a little more so the community can guide you better.

Comment: Does it have to me SQL Server or you are open for other options? If you are - you might consider document or schema-less databases such as MongoDB and CouchDB. They would fit to your problem naturally.

Comment: Once you have loaded and stored the data, what will you be doing with it? Does it just need to be filed away, will you be performing data mining or other analytics, do you need ready and immediate access to individual facts?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered a column of XML data type for the file data as an alternative of ColumnId -> Data structure? SQL server provides is a special dedicated [XML index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934097.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (over the entire XML structure) so your data can be fully indexed no matter what CSV columns you have. You will have much less records in the database to handle (as an entire CSV file will be a single XML field value). There are good XML query options to search by values & attributes of the XML type.

For that you will need to translate CSV to XML, but you will have to parse it either way ...

Not that your plan won't work, I am just giving an idea :)

=========================================================

Update with some online info:

An article from Simple talk: [The XML Methods in SQL Server](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/the-xml-methods-in-sql-server/)

Microsoft documentation for nodes() with various use case samples: [nodes() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx)

Microsoft document for value() with various use case samples: [value() Method (xml Data Type)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178030.aspx)

Comment: I've read that before, but honestly I discarded the idea before looking much into it. I thought that it will be difficult to access single rows of data which are stored in the xml.
I'll give it a try and have a closer look at that topic, thanks!
Quickly accessing the data in that XML data type wouldn't be a problem you say?

Comment: Well it is far less straight forward than pure SQL, but you have methods like nodes(), value(), exist() and modify() methods to work with the XML data. I will update my post with some articles / docs links so that you can get an idea. You were saying you don't really have a fixed and predefined columns set for CSV-s - XML is flexible. Joining / pivoting field-value structures for multiple columns is also painful sometimes, so you should choose the approach that suits your use case best.

Comment: ... and as I said - that is not the ultimate solution probably, but I have used it with good results for error & event logging of stored procedures or some dynamic sets of values that I need to store for reference or tracking. You should probably create a small mock up and try the queries, it takes some time initially until you get used to the methods.